# Capture and print stdout and stderr

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen, tee

I'm trying to capture and continue to print the stdout/stderr of subprocess.run. Basically looking for an internal tee function

objective (interactive python mode):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.run(['echo', 'random text'], stdout=(subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.STDOUT), stderr=(subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.STDERR))
random text
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> print(out)
'random text'
>>> print(err)
''
```

The code above doesn't work but it shows what I'm trying to accomplish. Any ideas on how to ensure stdout and stderr get printed normally but are also captured?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use subprocess.run to capture and print the output, but I ended up using popen to accomplish this. Popen doesn't allow timeouts therefore I had to us a signal handler to facilitate that.

```
def tee(command: Sequence[str], *args, **kwargs):
    import subprocess
    import select
    from signal import alarm, signal, SIGALRM, SIGKILL
    stdout2 = ''
    stderr2 = ''

    # timeout configuration
    class TimeoutAlarm(Exception):
        pass

    def timeout_alarm_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutAlarm

    # capture timeout if specified in kwargs
    timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout') if kwargs.get('timeout') else None  # type: # Optional[int]
    if timeout:
        assert isinstance(timeout, int), "Signal handler only support integers"
        signal(SIGALRM, timeout_alarm_handler)
        alarm(int(timeout))

    # Configure stdout and stderr if specified
    _ = kwargs.pop('stdout') if kwargs.get('stdout') else None
    _ = kwargs.pop('stderr') if kwargs.get('stderr') else None

    # remove universal_newlines as we always use universal_newlines
    _ = kwargs.pop('universal_newlines') if kwargs.get('universal_newlines') is not None else None

    # Execute a child program in a new process
    with subprocess.Popen(command, *args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, **kwargs) as process:
        try:  # TimeoutAlarm try block
            stdout_fn = process.stdout.fileno()
            stderr_fn = process.stderr.fileno()

            # Continue reading stdout and stderr as long as the process has not terminated
            while process.poll() is None:
                # blocks until one file descriptor is ready
                fds, _, _ = select.select([stdout_fn, stderr_fn], [], [])

                # Capture the stdout
                if stdout_fn in fds:
                    new_so = process.stdout.readline()
                    sys.stdout.write(new_so)
                    stdout2 += new_so

                # Capture the stderr
                if stderr_fn in fds:
                    new_se = process.stderr.readline()
                    sys.stderr.write(new_se)
                    stderr2 += new_se
            return_code = process.returncode
        except TimeoutAlarm:
            os.kill(process.pid, SIGKILL)
            return_code = process.returncode
            raise subprocess.TimeoutExpired(cmd=command, timeout=timeout)

    if return_code == 127:
        raise OSError('Command not found')
    elif return_code == 126:
        raise OSError('Command invoked cannot execute')

    return subprocess.CompletedProcess(args, return_code, stdout2, stderr2)
```

Thank Andrew Hoos for most of this: https://gist.github.com/AndrewHoos/9f03c74988469b517a7a